# AWS Data Pipeline extracting data from DynamoDB has different number of files than indicated in the manifest file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I extracted ~348 million row from DynamoDB using the data pipeline.  The pipeline completed with no errors.

I noticed the number of files in the S3 bucket is not the same as the number of files indicated in the manifest "entries" tag.  Each file contains 100,000 records and so there are 3,479 files.  There are 3,469 files in the "entries" tag in the resulting manifest.

Does anyone have any idea why?

The manifest file is required in order to import the files back into DynamoDB.  This is production data and the 10 file discrepancy could cost us 1 million rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - With a lot of research and support's help, I think I have solved this issue.  This has to do with speculative execution.  Essentially, if a process doesn't complete in time, a new process is kicked off and given the same work.  When the initial process finally completes, the secondary process is cancelled and doesn't clean up very well after itself.  Disabling this "feature" solved my issue.

To do so, you will need to create a custom pipeline definition.  To it add:

```
{
    "name": "disableSpeculativeExecution",
    "id": "disableSpeculativeExecution",
    "type": "EmrConfiguration",
    "classification": "mapred-site",
    "property": [
        {
            "ref": "disableSpeculativeExecutionForMapperTasks"
        },
        {
            "ref": "disableSpeculativeExecutionForMapperTasks"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "disableSpeculativeExecutionForMapperTasks",
    "id": "disableSpeculativeExecutionForMapperTasks",
    "type": "Property",
    "key": "mapreduce.map.speculative",
    "value": "false"
},
{
    "name": "disableSpeculativeExecutionForReducerTasks",
    "id": "disableSpeculativeExecutionForReducerTasks",
    "type": "Property",
    "key": "mapreduce.reduce.speculative",
    "value": "false"
},
```

Then inside of the EMRClusterForBackup definition, add the bolded reference:

> **"configuration": {  "ref": "disableSpeculativeExecution" }**

```
{
    "name": "EmrClusterForBackup",
    "coreInstanceCount": "1",
    "coreInstanceType": "m3.xlarge",
    "releaseLabel": "emr-5.13.0",
    "masterInstanceType": "m3.xlarge",
    "id": "EmrClusterForBackup",
    "region": "#{myDDBRegion}",
    "type": "EmrCluster",
    "terminateAfter" : "12 Hours",
    "configuration": {
        "ref": "disableSpeculativeExecution"
    }
},
```